# Is there any way to store file on virtual directory using c#?

Tags: c#, virtual-directory

I want to store file on the server and I have virtual directory path so how to store file on that location using c#?

Comment: You're writing a ASP.NET app, right? If you set permission first than you could write something  like
 using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/data.txt"), true))
 {
  file.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text); // Write the file.
 }